# Spring Security SAML2 - SP http post security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0

I have an application that I am adding Spring Security's SAML implementation.  For most of the IDPs that I am connecting to I use http post.  So my question is, since everything passes through the client, if you don't use signing/encryption, wouldn't the client, who is essentially the middle man, be able to easily modify the assertion in transport?  Am I missing something here?  What is the best practice for http-post with SAML?

** Update **

So after a bit more research, my understanding is that as long as the response is signed by the IDP the client will be able to view the assertion but won't be able to modify it, as long as you are verifying signatures on the SP.  So, if I am using ssl with signature verification, the only party that would be able to see any part of the response is the client, but they shouldn't be able to modify it, am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. The client can see the assertions, but as any sensitive data in them is about the user it doesn't matter.

In cases where it is inappropriate for the user to be able to read the assertion contents they can be sent via a back channel if using artifact binding, or they can be encrypted.

Regarding the integrity of the data, the SAML specification explicitly requires the receiving system to validate the signature of the data (either on response or on assertion level). Any data not protected by a signature must not be processed by the recipient.

Comment: but as any sensitive data in them is about the user it doesn't matter

is not really correct. A malicious Script could change assertion data, hence the Assertions must be signed when using a front-channel protocol.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Signatures on the response or assertions is a strict requirement by the spec, just as OP found out in the edit so I didn't mention it. Added it an edit.